# Shopify embedded app forcing https

Tags: shopify

Usually I can develop an embedded app locally by "allowing unsafe scripts" in chrome, as it even mentions in the embedded app sdk docs. However on Friday I noticed that it was no longer working and Shopify is trying to load the app iframe as https://localhost:3000 which doesn't work of course. Is there some change in the way Shopify handles embedded apps or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: you can always trick your localhost out to work https. That is not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify employee here. We've pushed a change today to allow http URLs for localhost. Other URLs are still upgraded to https. I do encourage you however to change your development environment to use https. This will allow you to avoid some basic problems when you push your change to production, for example with mixed content.